# Error installing Image Magick on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, imagick

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on DigitalOcean, I tried to install ImageMagick

I have found and followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/problem-installing-imagemagick-ubuntu-14-04) instruction

I have updated my installation with this command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I tried following

```
wget http://mirror.checkdomain.de/imagemagick/ImageMagick-6.9.2-10.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ImageMagick-6.9.2-10.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-6.9.2-10
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

But while it `sudo make` process, it returns error as you can see in the screen shot.

What I am doing wrong and how can I install it correctly?

[image]

Comment: open this Readme.bugs in any editor like nano. Here it's hard to say what exactly is problem

Comment: I would recommend compiling directly from the source, rather than a 3rd party site https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/tree/ImageMagick-6 and that is also a good place to report bugs. Though you may need to either report it to GCC project, or just use a different version of the compiler.

Comment: @piotrek1543 I agree, but since now it is fixed I will know that for future, thank you for contribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First all it is a good practice to have things updated:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Next, you should install imagemagick and php5-imagick from the repository:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick
```

And finally reload your web server.